# Kendo UI PDF Export multiple margin settings

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, pdf-generation

I have only a footer on an Kendo UI PDF Export template so I want a different margin on the bottom as opposed to the rest of the PDF page.  I see in the documentation for the PDFMarginComponenet there is top, bottom, right and left but I do not see anywhere on how to implement multiple options.

```
<kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" margin="'{top: 27, right: 27, left: 27, bottom: 50}'">
....
</kendo-pdf-export>
```

Here is a plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/jMaJfIdyn1wCoKrTeZ1v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer on Github with the Kendo team.  Needed to bind the property and submit them in order.

```
<kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" [margin]="{top: 27, bottom: 50, right: 27, left: 27}">
....
</kendo-pdf-export>
```

Attached is plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/HvL1kdiULjhfQPOcwqbe?p=preview

Here is the Github ticket.  https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1078